# Does the Quran say that the Universe is expanding?

Tags: quran, universe

There is quite bit of hype among Muslims who's says, it is in the Quran that the Universe is expanding. They quote the verse [51:47](http://quran.com/51/47). A link that quotes this  is [here](http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/1560/).

> **Sahih International**
>
> And the heaven We constructed with strength, and indeed, We are [its]
>   expander.

Sahih International translation says something but other translations say something else:

> **Pickthall**
>
> We have built the heaven with might, and We it is Who make
>   the vast extent (thereof).
>
> **Yusuf Ali**
>
> With power and skill did We
>   construct the Firmament: for it is We Who create the vastness of pace.
>
> **Shakir**
>
> And the heaven, We raised it high with power, and most surely
>   We are the makers of things ample.

What is the truth?

Comment: and could not it be said "wa inna la musiguna **ha** " with arabic grammar? so a pronoun would clearly refer to sky? may i or you add this to question?

Comment: Logically, we can not say that the Quran says it is expanding 100%. But the idea is surely there. The phrase "wa inna lamosi3on" could also mean "And surely We are able/have the power to". And in the same time, the phrase could also mean "And survely We are its expander!". See the word mosi3on has different meanings.

Comment: more translations of quran 51:47 : http://www.islamawakened.com/quran/51/47/default.htm

Comment: grammar: http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=51&verse=47

Answer (score 2):

Seeking for Ahadeeth about the issue the following comments may be given:

1. Both Earth's surface and Skies were created from water and air (الماء و الهوی), and were expanded and structured ..., there are Quranic and Hadeethwise evidences that the skies were created after Earth so that the big bang theory for which the red shift effect is considered a most important sign for its justification cannot be correct.
2. The earth was not growing any plant and the sky was not raining, so Allah led the skies to rain and the Earth to grow plants:

   > أَوَلَمْ يَرَ‌ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُ‌وا أَنَّ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْ‌ضَ
   >   كَانَتَا رَ‌تْقًا فَفَتَقْنَاهُمَا ۖ وَجَعَلْنَا مِنَ الْمَاءِ كُلَّ
   >   شَيْءٍ حَيٍّ ۖ أَفَلَا يُؤْمِنُونَ
   >   --[[Al-Anbiya,30](http://tanzil.net/#21:30)]
   >
   > see [تفسير القمي، ج‏2، ص: 69] for interpretation, the translations I saw available were not all very correct

   and this blessing of Allah is called expanding in sustenance (واسع الرزق) and being constantly expanding can imply the sky (*السماء comes from وسمة which means a resource for water الماء*) being raining and increasing in life span of the creatures living on Earth and their sustenances (also mentionوَ فِي السَّمَاءِ رِ‌زْقُكُمْ وَ مَا تُوعَدُونَ), see [بحار الأنوار (ط - بيروت)، ج‏، ۵۵، باب ۸] and [مجمع البحرين، ج‏4، ص: 403
   ] as a reference for this justification.
3. Some scholars also believe by موسعون Allah also might intend to mention the physical expanding of the skies and interpret this verse together with فتق السماء and then فاطر السموات. Although all of these can also be interpreted else ways. See the research around this issue in e.g. [قاموس قرآن، ج‏3، ص: 53-51].

   ---

**Conclusion**:

This issue is not fully resolved and understood by the scholars. However the stages of creation of the Earth(s) and Skies are explained in Ahadeeth although not all of those explanations are also easy to understand. And Allah is the All-knower

Comment: I think we shouldn't deny science because of ones own understanding of the Quran and Hadith. One should be careful in this field.

Answer (score -1):

Salam alaikom

If I understood your question correctly:
First of all you can't say the haven is a `place` like earth or anywhere else.
Haven is a level or viewpoint that we can't realize.
Think about an animal; It lives in humans world but can't precept our society.
In meraj (transition of prophet to other world) he won’t really go in very high altitudes.
But instead he go very up in levels of think an understanding. So your viewpoint is not clearly true about worlds.

Comment: It does not throw any light on what the question is asking. There is general belief among many Muslim that Quran says Universe is expanding. What is your view point on that?

Comment: @muslim1 I was thinking about understanding your question too bad.forgive me.thats why I wrote the second line of answer

Comment: you mean me'raj happend without going up and passing the material skies? So you don't agree his ascendant happen with his material body transported all along the journey? Of course فیکم عالم الکبیر inter-relates both concepts but you cannot deny the 7 skies being really skies, can you?

Comment: @muslim1, his answer as is actually answer your question like "no it doesn't mean necessarily universe is expanding since by skies there is implied some other concepts."

Comment: @owari, to put it in right way "Quran does not says universe is expending. The quoted link and hype among Muslims that Universe is expanding is most likely exaggeration and not correct". If you agree with that. Put that in your answer and I will mark it answered. Do not add 'necessarily'. The question is, does it or it does not. I think the answer is it does not.

Comment: @muslim1, actually I am not eligible of saying that, the verse might say it or not, just one might make sure what is meant by that. Let me check my commentary books maybe there will find some related Hadeeth ...

Comment: @owari this is very hard to understand for myself too.but as I can say, 7 skies are not what we can imagine from sky meaning.they are skies,but not something like our sky.

Comment: Isn't our sky one of the seven skies?

Comment: This is where we are wrong. When Quran was revealed the Sahabas and the prophet understood it **perfectly**. How can they know 7 skies and we don't' know. How can they know the Universe is expanding and we don't know. How could they know that Earth was created first in Universe and we don't know. COuld it be that what they thought was truth was totally wrong or we don't have the capacity **now** to understand Quran. Back then they perfectly understood it.

Comment: @muslim1 they did not understand all ayats. why you said this, probably you have no proofs.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. According to Ulamas (the religious authorities), the phrase ((انا لموسعون)) in this Ayah (verse), shows the continuity of expanding the universe. This case was proven by many scientists. I just bring you one example; Dr. George Gamow proved this in his book: the creation of the universe. He says that on the basis of the information from the galaxies, we found out the universe is being expanded continues.

Comment: Not eligible to comment on the issue (like other issues indeed) but anyway, can you also explain [this verse](http://tanzil.net/#13:41) using such logics? I doubt. I only can bring up some Islamic resources that seemingly cite the dark matter in physics but God Willing I won't, since science is not mature enough and reduction of verses of Quran to fit the physicist's current understanding of the universe can be dangerous. My opinion though.

Comment: more translations of quran 13:41 : http://www.islamawakened.com/quran/13/41/default.htm